# Object undefined in jquery, plus my links are pointing elsewhere

Tags: migrations

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462598/settings-for-pointing-to-correct-drupal-site) on stackoverflow earlier, not realizing this site existed.  Seems that this would be a better place for it.

In a nutshell, I've restored an existing drupal 7 site under the `public_html/migrated_site` folder on my hosted site.

When I browse that URL however I'm getting errors from jquery that the Drupal object doesn't exist, and all my links and images point to `public_html/migrated_site/sites/someothersite`...

..where `someothersite` is the name of the old subdierctory under `public_html` on the prior host.

I changed my `settings.conf` values to point to the migrated MySQL database, and that bit appears to have worked, in that the site is coming up, albeit unstyled and with the above jQuery and links errors.

However I'm not sure what could be going on above?  I've tried a few `RewriteBase` settings in .htaccess in both `public_html` and `public_html/migrated_site` (particularly, adding `RewriteBase /~hisusersite/migrated_site`) but nothing seems to have made a difference.

Comment: In addition to the RewriteBase, you'll want to set $base_url in settings.php. Note that for RewriteBase, it's relative to the URI, so you'd just use RewriteBase /migrated_site , and $base_url = '//whatever.com/migrated_site';

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal JS object not being defined is a symptom of it not loading core JS files. His previous site probably enabled JS aggregation that places the aggregated file in sites/someothersite/files/XXX.js. The same goes for the missing images. Have you copied over sites/someothersite/ from the previous host?

It sounds like sites/someothersite/settings.php was what his original host was using and configured for DB & files. Since you're now viewing the site on  **gator1111.hostgator.com** Drupal is using sites/default/settings.php.

This primer on drupal [multi-site settings](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site#domains-urls) might help to also explain what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The 'CSS/JS aggregated file gzip compression' setting in `settings.php` is set to 'off' and I did copy all the js files (in `files/js`) from the previous host over to this one.
I also renamed the folder from 'migrated_site' to 'default' but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Another thing I would check is .htaccess rules for **RewriteBase**, since you're moving the site to a subdir. Drupal gets wonky sometimes when you do that. Try setting it to **/~hisusername/migrated_site**